# Trace in ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, vb.net-2010

I need to implement the tracing in asp.net website. My requirement is to create a log(text) file and write errors to that file.
What i have done so far is added following settings to my webconfig.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="ServiceFaultInfoTrace" switchName="sourceSwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="ServiceFaultInfoTraceText" />
          <remove name="Default"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="sourceSwitch" value="Error"/>
    </switches>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="ServiceFaultInfoTraceText" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="ServiceFaultInfoTraceText" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="DateTime" initializeData="C:\Temp\Api-Errors.txt" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

And trying to write to log as following. It is creating the log file but writing all page lod unload events but not writing the information(in my case it is exception) that I want to write.

```
Dim _trace As New TraceSource("ServiceFaultInfoTrace", SourceLevels.Error)
_trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, ex.Message)
```

Comment: do you want to implement [*Tracing*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx "Asp.net Trace") or [*logging*](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling "Asp.net Error Handling & Logging") ?

Comment: Tracing in which i need to write errors to text file if there is any...

Comment: To log errors/exceptions, there is a concept called Logging. Tracing gives you ability to analyze page requests.

Comment: Yes you are right Tracing gives me the page request info but within trace you can see errors as well if you want to and thats why i need Tracing so that later on if i want to i can switch between anything. I was following this tutorial but it is not working for me. [link]http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149251/Debugging-Tracing-and-Instrumentation-in-NET-and-A

Comment: ok you want to trace request & log messages throughout request lifecycle. can you please check Trace configuration in your web.config, there should be one property **writeToDiagnosticsTrace** set to *True* which forward trace information to your listerners.

Comment: Yes I got that setting as well. My bad didn't post it...'code'<trace enabled="true" requestLimit="10" localOnly="false"  writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" pageOutput="false"/>

Answer (score 1):

Finally Guys I got it working and may be it will be Helpful to others in future. My project was a simple plain asp.net website(Not website projects) and to enable the trace I had to put in the complier setting in webconfig as following..

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"
                extension=".cs"
                compilerOptions="/d:TRACE"
                type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="0" />
      <compiler language="VB"
                extension=".vb"
                compilerOptions="/d:Trace=true"
                type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System,  Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"  warningLevel="0"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Others settings are as following

```
 <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="myTraceSource" switchName="mySwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <clear/>
          <add name="evengloglistener" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="myApp"/>
          <add name="delimitedListener" type="System.Diagnostics.DelimitedListTraceListener" delimiter="," initializeData="c:\Temp\outfile.csv.txt" traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime"/>
          <add name="textwriterListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\Temp\outfile.txt" traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="mySwitch" value="1"/>
    </switches>

  </system.diagnostics>
```

Under system.web tag put this

```
<trace enabled="true" mostRecent="true" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" pageOutput="false" />
```

And in code behind n aspx.vb page put this

```
Dim obj As New TraceSource("myTraceSource")


            obj.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Critical, 0, "This is a critical message")
            obj.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 0, "This is a simple warning message")
            obj.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.[Error], 0, "This is a error message")
            obj.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "Simple information message")
            obj.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, "Detail Verbose message")
            obj.Close()
```